# Android login app with cache

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an app with the cache. The app will check login credentials in the server and allow the user. I want the user to login only once like **Facebook**, **G mail** app etc..

As of now, I am trying to use **shared preferences** to store the login credentials for the first time and when the user tries to open the app next time I will log in with the stored credentials. But I want to simplify it like G mail app, **only once I need to log in** and next time when the user opens the app the login page should not be shown to him unless he logout.

In **onCreate** I am checking whether i have stored credentials or not if i have then i will login with that otherwise the user has to enter the login credentials and press login button.

```
sharedPref_login = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("login_credentials",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        username = sharedPref_login.getString("username", defaultValue);
        password = sharedPref_login.getString("password", defaultValue);
        roles = sharedPref_login.getString("roles", defaultValue);

        if (!username.equals("")){
            if (!isInternetOn()){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Restart the application once the internet connection established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Applogin(username, password, millisInString);

            }
        }
```

I want to avoid this method by log in only once unless he press logout button.

Comment: You can directly put the isLoggedIn flag in shared preference. If it's TRUE, navigate use to target screen else go for Login. 
Or, Is there a need for silent login for the server end?

Comment: there may not be a need but i thought it is a standard procedure to log in and i want to know how facebook and gmail apps are caching the login.

Comment: You can go ahead with this approach. Later if Auth token you are receiving from server becomes invalid. You can force logout user. That's approach most of the apps are taking.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I will go with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should  use `SharedPreferences`

This is for saving data:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.putString("password", password);
    editor.commit();
```

And this is to retrive it:

```
    SharedPreference prefs = getSharedPreferences("UserData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = prefs.getString("username","");
    String pwd = prefs.getString("password","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Fetching id from shared preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    sharedPreferences =getSharedPreferences(Constant.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    username = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF, "");
    password = sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.PASSWORD_SHARED_PREF, "");


if(!username.equals("")){ 
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class)
startActivity(intent)
}else{
     if (!isInternetOn()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Restart the application once the internet connection established", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Applogin(username, password, millisInString);

        }
}
```